# Cordova and iOS: Playing an audio from an iframe hosted in cdvfile://localhost

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, iframe, plugins

I have the following issue:
- In an iOS Cordova application, I downloaded an html page and its resources (css, audio, images) in cdvfile://localhost/persistent/myfolder/
- I load cdvfile://localhost/persistent/myfolder/index.html in an iframe.
- The page is properly displayed (css and images) but audios are not being able to load and play... a popup with "unsupported url" appears when trying to execute the audio...

I found lot of articles/post regarding this issue, but none of them have the particularity of playing audios from an iframe (I need to use an iframe, this is a must in my project)...

Any ideas? Remember than I'm not having access to cordova's plugins inside the iframe :-/

Comment: In Android, I was abled to do so, by sending the path to the parent and playing the audio by using the Media plugin.
In iOS, I'm not being able to communicate to the parent the URL, neither trying to call a parent function or by using parent.postMessage HTML5 function. :-(